# mvn jetty:run only builds the project, not starting the server

Tags: java, maven, jetty

according to Jetty website, "**mvn jetty:run**" "This starts Jetty and serves up your project on http://localhost:8080/". However it only builds my maven project and not starting the server. [After building, it returned to command prompt again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRmD3.png) I can start the sever by the following command though: **mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="xxxx.xxxxx.myMainClass**". But I wish mvn jetty:run could work.

I have the plug-in in my pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.34.v20201102</version>
    </plugin>
```

What did I miss? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`mvn jetty:run` is for maven projects that are `<packaging>war</packaging>`

The fact that you can run your project with a mainClass tells use that you are not using `<packaging>war</packaging>`